How to avoid opening grey screens when trying to hide the excel with VBA?
I'm learning to make apps with VBA in Excel. I was trying to make an app that opens a user form directly at the start, while Excel is being hidden.
The idea is: you open the file, you only see the user form without having to see Excel.
However, when I try to hide the workbook with VBA,it opens empty grey windows additionally. I can only close these windows in the task manager.
Why this happens and how can I fix it?

I tried using this code at the object ThisWorkbook in the vba editor:
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

    Application.Visible = False
    UserForm1.Show

    End Sub

It hides the main Excel screen, but shows those grey windows that I don't want. Then I tried not putting code in the ThisWorkbook object. And instead I used thus code in a module:
Sub Auto_open()

    UserForm1.Show

    End Sub

But it also opens the grey windows anyway.

I think the answer is not to try to hide the app, but to move it out of view. Try this code:
Option Explicit


Private myWindow As Window

Public Sub showForm()
    UserForm1.Show
    
    Set myWindow = Application.Windows(1)
    myWindow.WindowState = xlNormal

    '// move the window out of view here
    myWindow.Top = -1000
    UserForm1.Top = 50
    UserForm1.Left = 50
    
End Sub

Public Sub hideForm()

    myWindow.Top = 100
    myWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
    Unload UserForm1
    
End Sub


Yes, It worked! Thanks a lot!

Great, if you accept this answer please mark it as accepted. Thanks!
